# How to recompile php with ZTS enabled on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, thread-safety

I would like to use the multithreading PHP on Ubuntu, but when I try to install the package `pthread`, I get this error message:

> configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled.

Answer (score 4):

```
HOW TO INSTALL IN LINUX SYSTEM'S:
------------------------------------

1) Download PHP sources and Unpack PHP

2) Download PEAR
     wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
     php go-pear.phar

3) Download pthreads
Get PECL extension (PECL is a repository for PHP Extensions)

# pecl install pthread-0.4.4

4) Unpack pthreads
copy pthread-0.4.4  to  php/ext
(for ./configure allow  add option --enable-pthreads)

# mv build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads-master    build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads

5)  Reconfigure sources
# ./buildconf --force
# ./configure --help | grep pthreads

You should see the appropriate --enable-pthreads option listed as a result, if you do not, then

# rm -rf aclocal.m4
# rm -rf autom4te.cache/
# ./buildconf --force

6) Build PHP
Compile PHP source code
Add:
# ./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads

7) Installing PHP
# make
# sudo make install

8) Update php.ini
Add in php.ini
extension=pthreads.so
Include_path = “/usr/local/lib/php”

9) Check Modules
php -m (check pthread loaded)

10) Test Thread Class
# php SimpleTest.php
```

Comment: Doing pecl install pthread-0.4.4 I get the error:

No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pthread"
install failed

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this PPA repository to add PHP5 with ZTS enabled:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```